# How to find Not Versioned Files in TortoiseGit?

Tags: git, tortoisegit

I'm experimenting with Git and TortoiseGit, after many years of working in SVN.

I have a fairly large project that I'm using as a testbed (48,139 files in 10,505 directories).

I have successfully created a Git repository, added and committed the files, pushed them to a second bare repository, pulled them to a third repository, and everything is working fine.

Except - I copied in some of the changes from the originating SVN project. Part of these changes was the addition of a few new files.

When I go down into a directory that has a new file and use "TortoiseGit->Check for modifications" I clearly see the file listed with status unknown.

But when I do the same from the root directory of the project, the files are there, but they're buried a list of tens of thousands of ignored files, and are impossible to find.

That is, in the "Check for modifications" dialog, if I check the "Show unversioned files" and uncheck the "Show ignored files", I still see the ignored files.

The summary at the bottom right shows "files: normal=0, non-versioned=25485, modified=0, added=0, deleted=0, conflicted=0".

If I uncheck both "show unversioned" and "show ignored" I see no files in the list.

But if I check "show unversioned" and uncheck "show ignored" I still see 25,485 files in the list.

And I'd expect to see only the unversioned files that had not been ignored.

What am I doing wrong?

This is almost useless, as it is.

===

OK - I checked, before I asked this question, that I was running the most recent version of TortoiseGit.

I had not, though, checked that I was running the most recent version of Git for Windows.

I updated that, and I'm still seeing ignored files in "Check for modifications" when I check "Show unversioned files".

===

Edited again - it was, as was suggested, a problem in the .gitignore.

Rules I had added were no longer there, and without them TortoiseGit was reporting what it should have.

IOW: never mind.

Comment: As a sanity check, what does `git status` show, when you run it on the command line? Asking in case the problem is with your `.gitignore` itself.

Comment: At the time I was having the issue, I didn't run _git status_. I did run _git clean -n_ and it showed what I would have expected it to - it did not show the ignored files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was, as was suggested, a problem in the .gitignore.

Rules I had added were no longer there, and without them TortoiseGit was reporting what it should have.

IOW: never mind.